# Elastic movie recommendation based on user likes

Tags: elasticsearch

My goal is to build movie recommendations system.

I have 2 types:

**mymovies**

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_index": "mymovies",
    "_type": "mymovie",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
     "title" : "Funny title is here"
     "genre" : "Comedy"
     "movieViews" : 901142
    }
}
```

**user**

Sample Document:

```
{
  "Name" : "Doni de brun",
  "moviesLiked": [122,185,231,292,1]      
}
```

**First question:** How the genres can be extracted for each movie of a user ?

**Second question:** I've read a lot on aggregations, significant-terms and scoring, but still I'm a little confused on when to use what.

I realize that building an efficient recommendation system depends on my needs, but still:
Should I extract the genres, and then search by genre and most movieViews ? Or maybe use custom_scoring for that kind of system ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by answering your specific questions on how to use Elasticsearch.

1. To get at data that is nested inside of a field in your index you need to use the [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html). In this case, your `"genre"` field is indexed inside of a hidden document that you can't get access to without using the nested query. It works similarly to other query types so should be pretty easy to pick up and use.
2. Aggregations are a way to put your search results into useful buckets. Each type of aggregations focuses on a different aspect of the returned results to create those buckets. A valid use case for you would be returning every movie in the index and using an aggregation to cluster the movies by genre, runtime, actor, rating, etc. I have had great success using aggregations as part of a filtering tool. A user clicks on one of the returned buckets and only sees the items inside of it, filtering out all of the rest of the results.

Comment: thanks for making this more clear.
Can you provide an answer to my first question with a nested query ?

Comment: regarding this example from elastic docs:
GET /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title": "eggs" }}, 
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  { "match": { "comments.name": "john" }},
                  { "match": { "comments.age":  28     }}
                ]
        }}}}
      ]
}}}

In my case, looking at "path" how to I "STEP OUT" to mymovies index ??

Comment: I am a little confused by your question here. What do you mean by 'step out' to the mymovies index? If you are running this query on that index there is no 'stepping out' to do. You nested fields are still inside that same index, they are just in a document that is hidden from search results unless you use the ```nested``` query as you have. To search on nested and un-nested fields do: ```"query":{"bool":{"must":["match":{"topField":"a"},{"nested":..},{"anotherTopLevelField":"b"}...``` That will return results that match 2 top level fields and whatever is in your nested query.